# The inability to install the module on Python

Tags: command-line, module, pypi, python-3.8

I have a problem. When writing the "pip install pyowm" command to the console, the module is installed, but the system doesn't see it. For example, Phyton, when executing the command "impor pyowm", gives an error, and when writing the command "pyowm" to the console, the error "" pyowm " is not an external or internal command".
All of the above apply to other modules as well.
P.S. I use VS Code and Python v.3.8.3

Answer (score 0):

From https://github.com/csparpa/pyowm:

```py
from pyowm import OWM
```

The package name (`pyowm`) and the module name (`OWM`) do not necessarily need to correspond.

Answer (score 0):

You can't just use any tool just by name from the console.

You have to first enter `python` to the console and then try `import pyowm` again.

It should import pyowm. But later you may want to actually use pyowm. Then you use this import most of the time:

`from pyowm.owm import OWM`

Comment: Thanks , it worked when i did it with a console. Before I tried to do with a VS Code.